# Closing stuck Windows 10 window

Tags: windows-10

I got a window on top of all others saying: "You'll need a new app to open this microsoft-edge".
It can be selected (the screen grab for the image below recognises that this is the current window), but does not seem to respond. The OK button is greyed out, it cannot be moved off screen and does not respond to Alt-F4.
[image: You'll need a new app to open this]

It is not on the Alt-Tab list of things. Clicking outside the window works as normal, ie. other programs respond but this one stays. As it has no title, it isn't immediately obvious which process it belongs to (some internal one, which perhaps I shouldn't terminate anyway?)

So I think somehow I got Windows to try opening Edge with another program..(?), more interestingly, how do I get rid of the window? Thank you.

Comment: [How do I identify the process that owns a spurious dialog box?](//superuser.com/a/69713) and then kill the process in task manager.

Comment: OpenWith.exe . That worked, thank you. Do you want to reference in an answer or shall we see whether this question is counted as a duplicate first?

Comment: With your agreement I will close as a duplicate.

Comment: Go ahead. Perhaps this one can serve as a search result if nothing else.